# can jackson parse string partially?

Tags: java, json, http, jackson

I want to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to convert the Json payload of a HTTP request  to a Java object.

However, I care only about some fields in that object.

e.g.

```
Obj
{
String a,
String b,
C c {
     int d,
     long e
     }
}
```

I want `Jackson` to parse Json to a semi-populated Java object

e.g.

```
Obj
{
String a,
String b,
String c  // as string: { int d,long e} }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why in heavens would you want that?

Comment: I see no JSON in your question.

Comment: @Mena there are some members of inner classes that I don't care about and don't want to parse them

Comment: @user1065869 why don't you just use `@JsonIgnore` instead?

Comment: because I want to compare it to other Json string of same content. I want to compare them as strings. I don't need to parse all of the inner members

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are either looking for a propriety way of serializing and de-serializing property `c` from your example. For this purpose Jackson supplies the `JsonSerialize` and `JsonDeserialize` annotations. You can find more informations [here](https://www.sghill.net/how-do-i-write-a-jackson-json-serializer-deserializer.html).

Alternatively, you might want to ignore certain properties of your Java object during Jackson serialization. For this Jackson comes with a couple of [options](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown).